# Double Click in OpenFaces Tree/DataTable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, openfaces

How can I navigate from a JSF page to another after I did double click on a table row. I'm looking for an attribute such as `action` in `o:commandButton`.

Thank you for any advice!
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xhtml file**

```
<o:treeTable id="treeTable" var="element"
    ondblclick="openTargetListFromTable(event);"  ....
```

**JavaScript**

```
function openTargetList(event) {

  O$.ajax.request(
    this, 
    event, {
      execute:  'form1:treeTable', 
      render:   'form1:treeTable', 
      listener: 'treeTableBean.openElement'
    }
  );

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head I would use the ondblclick parameter and fire a javascript function to redirect to a page.  Other wise you can use action="page?faces-redirect=true" but that will only work for a single click.

My javascript is a little basic but I believe you can use

window.location="http://www.yourdomain.com/"

to redirect.

so

```
  <script>
            function redirect() {

        window.location="http://www.yourdomain.com/"
            }
</script>




<o:commandButton ondblclick="redirect()" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've found another solution.